# Is it possible to test a COM-exposed assembly from .NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, interop, com-interop

I have a .NET assembly which I have exposed to COM via a tlb file, and an installer which registers the tlb. I have manually checked that the installer works correctly and that COM clients can access the library. So far, so good...

However, I am trying to put together some automated system tests which check that the installer is working correctly. As part of that I have automated the installation on a VM, and I now want to make some calls to the installed COM library to verify that it is working correctly. I originally thought about writing some tests in VB6, but I already have a large suite of tests written in C#, which reference the .NET assembly. I was hoping that I could change these to reference the .tlb, but I get an error when I try this within VS2008:

The ActiveX type library 'blah.tlb' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.

Is there any way I can fool VS2008 into allowing me to add this reference, perhaps by editing the tlb file?

Googling hasn't come up with any solutions. All I've found is a Microsoft Connect article stating that this is "By Design": http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=120882

Comment: A couple of people have mentioned using tlbimp.exe. If I try tlbimp.exe blah.tlb I get the error:

"Type library blah was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Closest I've gotten to a solution is something like the following:

```
using System;
class ComClass
{
    public bool CallFunction(arg1, arg2)
    {
        Type ComType;
        object ComObject;

        ComType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Registered.ComClass");
        // Create an instance of your COM Registered Object.
        ComObject = Activator.CreateInstance(ComType);

        object[] args = new object[2];
        args[0] = arg1;
        args[1] = arg2;

        // Call the Method and cast return to whatever it should be.
        return (bool)ComType.InvokeMember("MethodToCall", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ComObject, args))
    }
}
```

It's not very pretty, but I think gets the point across.  You could of course put the ComObject instantiation into a constructor and wrap the rest of the calls to the object, but probably not necessary for test code.

Comment: +1 for Type.GetTypeFromProgID method, it can get COM type. I tried this, it works (but is there practical difference to directly adding a reference? I don't know).

Comment: `methodCOM` in the example should in fact be the `ComType` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a wrapper class to your installed COM component using TLBImp then run your tests against that. You'll basically be writing a .Net assembly, installing that to COM then testing against the wrapper class so your tests will be routed as if it was called by a COM component

Comment: Emmm..No! You cant have a managed COM server and client. TlbImp will just fail...

Answer (score -1):

Using [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(VS.80).aspx) you can generate an assembly from your COM component that can be used in .NET code

Comment: Not if the COM component was created in C# or other .NET language

Comment: -1 reason same as comment: Not if the COM component was created in C# or other .NET language